# how to compile user input C program and show the output in a ruby on rails web application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-applications, rubygems

I'm trying to build an E-learning application

The  user reads the tutorial and tries to type in his own C program.

I want the web app to take this input and compile it,and show the appropriate output to the user.

I'm confused as to how I'm supposed to approach this problem.......are there any pre-existing libraries or gems for this or am I supposed to write a compiler from scratch ??

Comment: I can give you idea just like in your app after user select language let `C` he will write his code......wrap the code and make a file using ruby `File` if it is select c then file should be .c extension .........In your controller check and `file blank?` and others........ now use `system cc program.c`...... your server where your application is running in production  must have installed c .....use options in the method to access options for compilation like `-o`...etc

Comment: What do you plan to do about people that will put [`system`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/system.html) calls or fork bombs in their C code?

Comment: yes....security would be an issue,I guess I'll have to filter the input before passing it on to the compiler to deny access whenever someone types in system calls.Maybe I'll have to fiddle around with the privilege settings on the server.Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @mu is too short: I'd assume the compiled code should run on a very simple purpose-built scratch VM, with next to nothing installed other than the terminal and other essentials to run C code. It should probably use a different OS (C should be cross-compiled to it), and be reset to snapshot before each run. And amount of time/CPU assigned to the VM running the code should be strictly limited.

Comment: For Security: follow my first instruction now open the File if it is saved as .c extension ....as @mu state check any code that will hamper your server or data like let say `infinite loop`....use `benchmark` for getting execution time if it is taking more time stop execution throw validation error....if it is fetching data from ou server throw validation error....if it is sending huge data to crash your server got the `params` check the size throw validation ....check first size of the codes or files...then check is it using proper header of c ...then check `main()` is written or not

Comment: @RajarshiDas: How do you propose to detect an infinite loop?

Comment: @mu First of all in his application no one will execute a 30 lacs lines of code execution time will be more than 30 hours....so by checking the execution time using `benchmark` ..... in Linux we have `DETECT_SOFTLOCKUP` and `DETECT_HUNG_TASK` if he used as a server he can set it

Comment: @RajarshiDas: So now it is a challenge to see what sort of nastiness we can get past your filters. The point is that your "you can't do A, B, ..." approach is flawed. Neil's "throw it all in a separate locked down VM" idea seems a lot more sensible.

Comment: @mu..."to see what sort of nastiness we can get past your filters
"..... what do you mean? I am just suggesting....remember he should have to check the lines of code and its execution time hope you understand.....before throwing critics check yourself where you stayed

Answer (score 2):

There is a gem called [RubyInline](http://www.zenspider.com/ZSS/Products/RubyInline/) that you might be able to use. I was looking into something similar recently. This let you input a string that is a c-program and run it.

Have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.rubyinside.com/how-to-create-a-ruby-extension-in-c-in-under-5-minutes-100.html), and be sure to have look at the first comment in there.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'RubyInline'
class Example
  inline(:C) do |builder|
    builder.c "int method_test1() {
      int x = 10;
      return x;
    }"
  end
end

p Example.new.method_test1 #This prints out the result of the code, and I believe also errors if there are any
```

I am aware that this is not 100% the solution you are after, but it might nudge you in the right direction.